How to Recommend Enhancements Based on Multiple Criteria Without Always Having User ID?
I'm working on a recommendation system that suggests enhancements (additional services) to users based on the name of the massage, service length, center name, and occasionally, user details. However, I've encountered a couple of challenges that I need help with.
The datasets involved are structured as follows:
User Dataset: Contains USER_ID, AGE, GENDER, ZIPCODE, and BASE_CENTER.
Item Dataset: Contains ITEM_ID and ITEM_NAME (representing the enhancement).
Interaction Dataset: Includes USER_ID, ITEM_ID, TIMESTAMP, SERVICE_LENGTH, MASSAGE_NAME, CENTER_NAME, and EVENT_TYPE.
A notable aspect of my system is that each enhancement can be associated with more than one massage name and center name. Here are the specific issues I'm facing:
User ID Absence: In many cases, I don't have the USER_ID. What's the best practice for handling such instances in the recommendation process? Should I default to a generic user profile, or is there a more sophisticated approach to maintain personalization without user identification?
Inconsistent Recommendations Across Different Centers: I've observed that different centers sometimes yield the same enhancement recommendations, even though I expected the center name to influence the variety of suggestions. Moreover, changes in user age, gender, and center name don't seem to alter the results as anticipated.
Identical Results for Varied Inputs: Regardless of the variations in age, gender, and center name inputs, the system tends to recommend the same enhancements. I'm looking for strategies to diversify the outcomes and make the recommendations more sensitive to these input variables.
Questions:
How can I improve my recommendation system to handle instances without user IDs effectively, ensuring some level of personalization?
What strategies or models could I employ to make my system more responsive to variations in user details (age, gender) and center names, thereby offering more diverse and relevant enhancement recommendations?
Any insights or suggestions on how to address these challenges would be greatly appreciated.
Tried changing the schema but did not get much difference in output
